# Query string argument of EXECUTE is null

Tags: postgresql, bucles, function, cursor

Estoy haciendo  una función para que me de indicaciones un servicio de rutas y me lo devuelva en formato XLM.
Saca algo la query pero no todo y me salta un error que una de las query que se ejecuta es NULL. 
Esta es la query:

```
-- Function: xml_directions(integer, integer, text)

DROP FUNCTION xml_directions(integer, integer, text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xml_directions(source_id integer, target_id
integer, tab_name text)
  RETURNS xml AS
$BODY$DECLARE

start_point geometry; --geometria del punto inicial
tab_name text :=$3; -- nombre de la tabla (ways)
s_id integer :=$1; -- source id
t_id integer :=$2; -- target id
_first boolean :=true; --primer paso del algoritmo
fc real:= 111073.2835905824; -- factor de conversión multiplicativo para distancias
_A geometry;
_B geometry;
_C geometry;
_D geometry;
a1 float; -- azimuth de la primera geometria
a2 float; -- azimuth de la segunda geometria
angoli real[]; -- matriz de angulos (diferencia)
i integer; -- entero para desplazar: NB se define fuera del bucle, porque tambien sirve para obtener la longitud de las matrices

the_route CURSOR FOR SELECT rt.gid, rt.the_geom as geom, length(rt.the_geom) as length, ways.name::text AS NAME_1
FROM
(SELECT ways.gid, dijkstra.*, ST_AStext(ways.the_geom) as the_geom FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra
            ('SELECT gid as id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM ' || $3, $1, $2, true)) as dijkstra
            LEFT JOIN ways on ways.gid = dijkstra.edge) as rt  
        LEFT JOIN ways ON ways.gid = rt.gid;
--variables que hay que buscar
GID_1 integer;
GID_2 integer;
GEOM_1 geometry;
GEOM_2 geometry;
LENGTH_1 real;
LENGTH_2 real;
NAME_1 text;
NAME_2 text;




directions text[]; --variable que contiene los codigos relacionados con las maniobras
lengths real[]; --vector que contiene las longitudes de las secciones a recorrer
streets text[]; --vector que contiene los nombres de las rutas
geoms geometry[]; --vector de las geometrias individuales
line geometry; --geometria de la ruta general
tot_len real :=0;
tot_time real:=0;
tlu text := 'm'; -- tipo de unidad distancia

-- variable para la ejecucion de la consulta para la composición del xml
pre_string text;


steps_fragment text:='XMLELEMENT(NAME step,XMLELEMENT(NAME text,''Start from ';
line_fragment text;

xml_result xml;

BEGIN

angoli[0] :=0; -- la primera indicación es siempre "continuar por ...". El relleno del vector de ángulos debe comenzar desde ángulos [1]
i:=0;
OPEN the_route;
FETCH the_route INTO GID_1, GEOM_1, LENGTH_1, NAME_1;
 IF NAME_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
streets[0]:= replace(trim(both from NAME_1),'''','''''');
ELSE streets[0]:='Missing Street Name';
END IF;
 lengths[0]:= LENGTH_1*fc;
tot_len := tot_len + lengths[0];
line:=ST_Union(GEOM_1);
RAISE NOTICE ' STREET [0] = %',streets[0];
RAISE NOTICE ' LENGTHS [0] = %',lengths[0];
LOOP
FETCH the_route INTO GID_2, GEOM_2, LENGTH_2, NAME_2;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

-- caso primer segmento
 IF _first THEN
-- Averiguando punto de partida
_A :=ST_PointN(GEOM_1,1);
_B :=ST_PointN(GEOM_1,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_1));
_C :=ST_PointN(GEOM_2,1);
_D :=ST_PointN(GEOM_2,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_2));
IF (ST_Equals(_A, _C)) THEN
start_point := _B;
 ELSIF (ST_Equals(_A, _D)) THEN
start_point := _B;
 ELSE
start_point := _A;
 END IF;
 --Calculo que punto final de la primera geometria está conectado al punto de inicio y si es necesario, volteo la geometría
IF NOT(ST_Equals(start_point,ST_PointN(GEOM_1,1))) THEN -- El punto de inicio no coincide con el primer punto del segmento, por lo que el segmento debe voltearse
GEOM_1 := ST_Reverse(GEOM_1);
 END IF;
geoms[i]:= GEOM_1;
 start_point:= ST_PointN(Geom_1,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_1)); --Actualizo el punto de inicio como el ùltimo punto de la primera geometria

--Calculo que punto final de la segunda geometria está conectado al último punto de la primera geometria, si es necesario inserto la segunda geometria
IF NOT(ST_Equals(start_point, ST_PointN(GEOM_2,1))) THEN
GEOM_2 := ST_Reverse(GEOM_2);
 END IF;
start_point:= ST_PointN(Geom_2,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_2)); -- Actualizar el punto de inicio para el siguiente paso del bucle

--Los segmentos esán orientados. Calculo el azimuth y defino la direccion
a1 :=
trunc(ST_Azimuth(ST_PointN(GEOM_1,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_1)-1),ST_PointN(GEOM_1,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_1)))/(2*pi())*360);
 a2 :=
trunc(ST_Azimuth(ST_PointN(GEOM_2,1),ST_PointN(GEOM_2,2))/(2*pi())*360);
--La diferencia de los dos angulos define la maniobra a realizar, por lo que debe ser devuelta de cualquier manera
angoli[i+1] := (a1 - a2);
IF (angoli[i+1] >180.0) THEN angoli[i+1]:=angoli[i+1]-360;
END IF;
IF (angoli[i+1]< -180) THEN angoli[i+1]:=angoli[i+1]+360;
END IF;
IF NAME_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
streets[i+1]:= replace(trim(both from NAME_2),'''','''''');
ELSE
streets[i+1]:='nome strada mancante';
END IF;
--Si las calles tienen el mismo nombre
 IF ((streets[i+1] =streets[i])) THEN
 geoms[i]:=ST_Union(geoms[i],GEOM_2);
lengths[i]:=lengths[i]+(LENGTH_2 * fc);
line:=ST_Union(line,GEOM_2);
GEOM_1 := GEOM_2;
NAME_1 := NAME_2;
 ELSE
lengths[i+1]:= LENGTH_2 * fc;
 geoms[i+1]:= GEOM_2;
line:=ST_Union(line,GEOM_2);

i:= i+1;
 GID_1 := GID_2;
GEOM_1 := GEOM_2;
LENGTH_1 := LENGTH_2 * fc;
NAME_1 := NAME_2;
END IF;
 _first := false;

--Segmentos que siguen la orientacion del primero
ELSE
IF NOT(ST_Equals(start_point, ST_PointN(GEOM_2,1))) THEN
GEOM_2 := ST_Reverse(GEOM_2);
 END IF;
start_point:= ST_PointN(Geom_2,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_2)); -- aggiorno lo start point per lo step successivo del loop

-- Los segmentos estn orientados. Calculo azimuth y defino la direccion
a1 :=
trunc(ST_Azimuth(ST_PointN(GEOM_1,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_1)-1),ST_PointN(GEOM_1,ST_NumPoints(GEOM_1)))/(2*pi())*360);
 a2 :=
trunc(ST_Azimuth(ST_PointN(GEOM_2,1),ST_PointN(GEOM_2,2))/(2*pi())*360);
--la diferencia de los angulos define la maniobra a realizar
 angoli[i+1] := (a1 - a2);
IF (angoli[i+1] >180) THEN angoli[i+1]:=angoli[i+1]-360;
END IF;
IF (angoli[i+1]< -180) THEN angoli[i+1]:=angoli[i+1]+360;
END IF;

IF NAME_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
streets[i+1]:= replace(trim(both from NAME_2),'''','''''');
ELSE
streets[i+1]:='nome strada mancante';
END IF;

--Si las calles tienen el mismo nombre
IF ( (streets[i+1] =streets[i])) THEN
 geoms[i]:=ST_Union(geoms[i],GEOM_2);
lengths[i]:=lengths[i]+(LENGTH_2 * fc);
line:=ST_Union(line,GEOM_2);
GEOM_1 := GEOM_2;
NAME_1 := NAME_2;

ELSE


lengths[i+1]:= LENGTH_2 * fc;
tot_len := tot_len + lengths[i+1];
geoms[i+1]:=GEOM_2;

line:=ST_Union(line,GEOM_2);
 i:= i+1;
GID_1 := GID_2;
GEOM_1 := GEOM_2;
LENGTH_1 := LENGTH_2 * fc;
NAME_1 := NAME_2;
END IF;

END IF;

END LOOP;
  CLOSE the_route;

--Codigo angulos en maniobras
for k in 0..i LOOP
CASE
WHEN angoli[k]>=-5 AND angoli[k]<=5 THEN
directions[k]:='Sigue recto';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 1    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>=-45 AND angoli[k]<-5 THEN
directions[k]:='Gira levemente a la derecha';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 2    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>=-100 AND angoli[k]<-45 THEN
directions[k]:='Gire a la derecha';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 3    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>=-135 AND angoli[k]<-100 THEN
directions[k]:='Doblar a la derecha en ';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 4    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>=-180 AND angoli[k]<-135 THEN
directions[k]:='Gire en U hacia la derecha';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 5    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>5 AND angoli[k]<=45 THEN
directions[k]:='Gire levemente a la izquierda hacia ';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 6    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>45 AND angoli[k]<=100 THEN
directions[k]:='Gire a la izquierda en ';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 7    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>100 AND angoli[k]<=135 THEN
directions[k]:='doblar a la izquierda en';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 8    %',directions[k];
WHEN angoli[k]>135 AND angoli[k]<=180 THEN
directions[k]:='Gire en U hacia la izquierda';
RAISE NOTICE'RAMO 9    %',directions[k];
ELSE RAISE NOTICE' ELSE%',directions[k];
END CASE;
tot_len := tot_len + lengths[k];
END LOOP;
tot_len := trunc(tot_len);
tot_time := trunc(tot_len/833.33333); -- Se asume la velocidad media

IF (tot_len >= 1000) THEN
tot_len := tot_len/1000;
tlu := 'km';
END IF;
pre_string:='XMLROOT(XMLELEMENT(NAME result, XMLELEMENT(NAME route,
XMLELEMENT(NAME total_length, ''circa '||tot_len||' '||tlu||'''),
XMLELEMENT( NAME total_estimated_time, ''about '||tot_time||' min''),
XMLELEMENT(NAME directions,';
steps_fragment := steps_fragment||streets[0]||'''))';
for j in 0..i LOOP
RAISE NOTICE'geometria ------- %/',ST_AsText(geoms[j]);
steps_fragment := steps_fragment||',XMLELEMENT(NAME step,XMLELEMENT(NAME
text,'||''''||directions[j]||' '||streets[j]||' (about
'||trunc(lengths[j])||' m)'||''''||'),XMLELEMENT(NAME
line,'''||ST_AsText(geoms[j])||'''))';
END LOOP;
 line_fragment:='),XMLELEMENT(NAME
complete_line,'''||ST_AsText(line)||'''))),VERSION 1.0,STANDALONE YES)';
RAISE NOTICE'geometria -----------------------\n
--------------------------------------- \n\n%\n\n----------------------------------------',ST_AsText(line);

EXECUTE  'SELECT  '||pre_string||steps_fragment||line_fragment INTO
xml_result;

RETURN xml_result;

END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION xml_directions(integer, integer, text) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Cuando hago la consulta:

`SELECT * FROM xml_directions(26929, 7926, 'ways')`

Me salta con el error de **PL/pgSQL function xml_directions(integer,integer,text) line 249 at EXECUTE**

A ver si alguien puede averiguar el error. Le he dado bastantes vueltas y no encuentro el fallo. Supongo que el fallo puede estar por la variable **pre_string:='XMLROOT(XMLELEMENT(NAME result, XMLELEMENT(NAME route,
XMLELEMENT(NAME total_length, ''circa '||tot_len||' '||tlu||'''),
XMLELEMENT( NAME total_estimated_time, ''about '||tot_time||' min''),
XMLELEMENT(NAME directions,';**

Comment: Parece que te falta cerrar con una comilla simple: `EXECUTE  'SELECT  '||pre_string||steps_fragment||line_fragment' INTO
xml_result;`  Otra cosa, pon un espacio entre `NOTICE` y `'geometria` aquí: `RAISE NOTICE'geometria --------` , puede que no sea motivo de error, pero cuida tu ortografía, codificador :) Saludos

Comment: Buenos días. 
Gracias por la respuesta. He probado a meterle la comilla despues de ```line_fragment``` pero con esto me coge la comilla hasta el final de la query.
Las dos comillas esas se abren en el SELECT y se cierran despues del SELECT

Comment: Sería una cosa así:
```EXECUTE  'SELECT  ' ||pre_string||steps_fragment||line_fragment INTO
xml_result;```

Comment: Por si sirve de ayuda o guía. Este es el mensaje completo que me salta al hacer la query:
```NOTICE:   STREET [0] = Avenida Casado del Alisal
NOTICE:   LENGTHS [0] = 6.10903e+06
NOTICE:  RAMO 1    Sigue recto
NOTICE:  RAMO 3    Gire a la derecha
NOTICE:  RAMO 2    Gira levemente a la derecha
NOTICE:  RAMO 7    Gire a la izquierda en```